# colorbar eastoutside vs westoutside

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I put two colorbars in the same image using [this submission](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24371-colormap-and-colorbar-utilities--jul-2014-) on filexchange.

[image]

The position of the first colorbar is set by:

```
colorbar('WestOutside')
```

the position of the second one by:

```
colorbar('EastOutside')
```

Does anyone know why the first one is longer?

When looking at the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) it seemed to me that they should be the same. What am I missing?

The skeleton of the code is the following:

```
%define coordinates of the nodes
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,33);
[x,y]=pol2cart(theta,1);

%define colormap of the links
cm = winter;
colormap(cm);

%plot the links
for ii=1:N
quiver(...)
end

%place the first colorbar
hcb=colorbar('EastOutside');

%freeze the first colorbar
cbfreeze(hcb);


%define the second colormap
cm = autumn;
colormap(cm);

%plot the dots
for ii=1:N
plot(...)
end

%place the second colorbar
hb=colorbar('EastOutside');
```

Comment: I suggest you post a bit more code showing how you created your plot

Comment: Nice plot! I would try creating the axis first, then add your colorbars explicitly specifying this axis, then do your plots also explicitly specifying the axis. It looks like the first colormap is created before the axis is populated, so it may be resized by your plots.

Comment: @HughNolan thanks, but I do not know how to do it. how can I first create the axis and then make the plot?

Comment: Use `ax=axes;` then pass `ax` into your `quiver`, `colorbar` and `plot` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use two different axes. Based on your code:

```
%define coordinates of the nodes
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,33);
[x,y]=pol2cart(theta,1);

%plot the links
close
figure;
for ii=1:100
    quiver(x,y)
end
%define colormap of the links
ax1 = gca;
colormap (ax1,winter)
%place the first colorbar
hcb=colorbar(ax1,'EastOutside');
%this is tentative, just to get the axes right position:
hb=colorbar(ax1,'WestOutside'); 
pos = ax1.Position;
hb.delete
% second colorbar
ax2 = axes;
colormap (ax2,autumn)
hb=colorbar(ax2,'WestOutside');
ax2.Position = pos;
axis off
ax1.Position = pos;
```

It creates this:
[image]

Using MATLAB 2015a.