# Legend only affects to one of the linked axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The following MVCE reproduces a problem that I am experiencing when displaying a legend in a figure that has several axes objects.

In order to plot an elevation profile of the terrain I use two axes:

- `ax(1)` for the sky in the background
- `ax(2)` for the terrain in the foreground

[image: Vertical profile, legend]

During the plotting tasks I work with each set of axes independently and at the end of the process I link `ax(1)` and `ax(2)` using `linkaxes(ax, 'xy')` so that they remain synchronized dimensionally.

Finally, I add a [`legend`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) in the `'southoutside'` location but only the foreground axes are automatically shrinked to allow space for the legend, the background axes stay unchanged, thus interfering with the intended layout, as shown in the following image:

[image: Vertical profile, legend, bad axes]

The very purpose of using [`linkaxes`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html) was to prevent this undesired behavior.

I would be grateful if someone could shed some light on how to solve this problem.

---

### Update

In response to gnovice [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294008/legend-only-affects-to-one-of-the-linked-axes#comment69793053_41294008):

The reason why I am using two axes is because I thought it was the only possible way to combine different colormaps in the same figure. Note that for the sky I use `sky_map` and for the terrain I use the [`demcmap`](https://mathworks.com/help/map/ref/demcmap.html) function which sets a different colormap.

---

### Code

```
% Create figure.
figure;

% Create background axes for the sky.
ax(1) = axes;

% Sky data for background.
x_bg = [0, 0, 10, 10];
y_bg = [0, 10, 10, 0];

% Fill sky with color gradient on y-axis.
fill(x_bg, y_bg, y_bg);

% Generate custom sky colormap.
sky_map = interp1([0, 1], [135, 206, 235; 255, 255, 255]./255, linspace(0, 1, 255));

% Apply sky colormap.
colormap(ax(1), sky_map);

% Create foreground axes for the terrain.
ax(2) = axes;

% Terrain data.
x = [0, 0:10, 10];
y = [0, 5*rand(size(0:10)), 0];

% Fill terrain.
fill(x, y, y);

% Sets the colormap and color axis limits based on the elevation data
% limits.
demcmap(y);

% Link x-axis and y-axis of ax(1) and ax(2).
linkaxes(ax, 'xy');

% Hide ax(1).
set(ax(1), 'Visible', 'off');

% Transparent background for ax(2).
set(ax(2), 'Color', 'none');

% Display title.
title('Vertical Profile');

% Display legend underneath.
legend('Terrain', 'Location', 'southoutside');
```

Comment: `linkaxes` only syncs axes *limits*. You'll need to sync properties (like `Position`) with [`linkprop`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkprop.html)

Comment: Thanks @excaza you got it right! As you suggested, I used `linkprop(ax, 'Position');` and it solved the problem. I encourage you to post an official answer :)

Comment: I have to ask... why are you using two axes? Couldn't you plot the two filled polygons on the same axes, then modify the `'ZData'` property of each patch to ensure they are layered properly?

Comment: @gnovice Thanks a lot for your comment! In fact your comment is very convenient because even though excaza's approach solves the problem for this MVCE, it didn't work in my real case (which is more elaborate), so the limits of the two axes still don't match in my real case. I am using two axes because I thought it was the only possible way to combine different colormaps in the same figure. Working with only one axes would be a lot simpler indeed. Since I have never manipulated the `ZData` property, I don't know its potential. Is there any resource that you could point me to? Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Cebri: Having multiple objects that need their own colormaps is tricky, but you can usually get around it by defining object colors so that they are RGB colors instead of colormap indices. For example, the `fill` command you use is really just creating `patch` objects, so for the sky background you could just make a patch object directly, paying special attention to how you define the [`C` input argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#inputarg_C). The sky could be made without a colormap, so the terrain could use it.

Comment: I have included both solutions in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1: Using two axes and [`linkprop`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkprop.html).

Quoting excaza's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294008/legend-only-affects-to-one-of-the-linked-axes#comment69791327_41294008):

> [`linkaxes`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html) only syncs axes limits. You'll need to sync properties
>   (like `Position`) with [`linkprop`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkprop.html)

Add `linkprop(ax, 'Position');` before calling [`legend`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html).

Result:

[image: Method 1]

As a side note, if you wish to learn more, I suggest reading "[Using linkaxes vs. linkprop](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/using-linkaxes-vs-linkprop)" from Undocumented Matlab, specially to solve the problem of `linkaxes` being overriden by each other.

---

Code:

```
% Create figure.
figure;

% Create background axes for the sky.
ax(1) = axes;

% Sky data for background.
x_bg = [0, 0, 10, 10];
y_bg = [0, 10, 10, 0];

% Fill sky with color gradient on y-axis.
fill(x_bg, y_bg, y_bg);

% Generate custom sky colormap.
sky_map = interp1([0, 1], [135, 206, 235; 255, 255, 255]./255, linspace(0, 1, 255));

% Apply sky colormap.
colormap(ax(1), sky_map);

% Create foreground axes for the terrain.
ax(2) = axes;

% Terrain data.
x = [0, 0:10, 10];
y = [0, 5*rand(size(0:10)), 0];

% Fill terrain.
fill(x, y, y);

% Sets the colormap and color axis limits based on the elevation data
% limits.
demcmap(y);

% Link x-axis and y-axis limits of ax(1) and ax(2).
linkaxes(ax, 'xy');

% Link Position property of ax(1) and ax(2).
linkprop(ax, 'Position');

% Hide ax(1).
set(ax(1), 'Visible', 'off');

% Transparent background for ax(2).
set(ax(2), 'Color', 'none');

% Display title.
title('Vertical Profile');

% Display legend underneath.
legend('Terrain', 'Location', 'southoutside');
```

---

### Method 2: Using one axes and modifying `'FaceVertexCData'`

Quoting gnovice's comments [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294008/legend-only-affects-to-one-of-the-linked-axes#comment69793053_41294008) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294008/legend-only-affects-to-one-of-the-linked-axes#comment69793890_41294008):

> I have to ask... why are you using two axes? Couldn't you plot the two
>   filled polygons on the same axes, then modify the `ZData` property of
>   each patch to ensure they are layered properly?
>
> Having multiple objects that need their own colormaps is tricky, but
>   you can usually get around it by defining object colors so that they
>   are RGB colors instead of colormap indices. For example, the [`fill`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html)
>   command you use is really just creating [`patch`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) objects, so for the sky
>   background you could just make a patch object directly, paying special
>   attention to how you define the [`C` input argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#inputarg_C). The sky could be
>   made without a colormap, so the terrain could use it.

For the sky part, replace [`fill`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) with [`patch`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) and set [`hold on`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html). And then modify the `'FaceVertexCData'` property with an array of true color RGB values (see [Patch Properties](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html)).

In my code below, the true color array is called `CData` and is defined by:

```
% True color array.
CData = [sky_map(1, :); sky_map(end, :); sky_map(end, :); sky_map(1, :)];
```

which looks like this:

```
CData =

    0.5294    0.8078    0.9216
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
    0.5294    0.8078    0.9216
```

then use [`set`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) with the patch handle `h1`:

```
% Apply sky colormap to 'FaceVertexCData' property.
set(h1, 'FaceVertexCData', CData);
```

Result:

[image: Method 2]

---

Code:

```
% Create figure.
figure;

% Sky data for background.
x_bg = [0, 0, 10, 10];
y_bg = [0, 10, 10, 0];

% Sky indexed colors.
c_bg = [0, 1, 1, 0];

% Patch sky using default colormap (parula).
h1 = patch(x_bg, y_bg, c_bg);

% Generate custom sky colormap.
sky_map = interp1([0, 1], [135, 206, 235; 255, 255, 255]./255, linspace(0, 1, 255));

% True color array.
CData = [sky_map(1, :); sky_map(end, :); sky_map(end, :); sky_map(1, :)];

% Apply sky colormap to 'FaceVertexCData' property.
set(h1, 'FaceVertexCData', CData);

% Retain sky patch in the current axes.
hold on;

% Terrain data.
x = [0, 0:10, 10];
y = [0, 5*rand(size(0:10)), 0];

% Fill terrain.
h2 = fill(x, y, y);

% Sets the colormap and color axis limits based on the elevation data
% limits.
demcmap(y);

% Display title.
title('Vertical Profile');

% Display legend underneath.
legend(h2, 'Terrain', 'Location', 'southoutside');
```

---

### Differences

Note that the results generated with Method 1 and Method 2 are very similar but not the same:

Method 1:

- Slightly smaller figure.
- Tick marks are visible.
- Gray color for legend backgound.

Method 2:

- Slightly bigger figure.
- Tick marks are not visible.
- White color for legend backgound.

Answer (score 3):

You **can** use 2 colormaps on the same figure with the following workaround. The main idea is to concatenate all the colormaps you want to use in one colormap, and then choose which part of the colormap you use:

```
maxHight = 5;
xmax = 10;
% Sky data for background:
x_bg = [0, 0, 1, 1];
y_bg = [0, 1, 1, 0];

% Terrain data:
x = [0 0:xmax xmax];
y = [0 maxHight*rand(size(x(2:end-1))) 0];

% Custom sky colormap:
sky_map = interp1([0, 1], [135, 206, 235; 255, 255, 255]./255, linspace(0, 1, 255));

% Terrain colormap:
tmap = demcmap(y);

% concat both colormaps:
cmap = [tmap;sky_map];

% use the new colormap on the figure:
colormap(cmap);

% Create background axes for the sky:
ax(1) = axes;

% plot the sky as a patch:
patch(x_bg,y_bg,y_bg,'LineStyle','none')

% define the part of the colormap to use:
ax(1).CLim = [-(size(sky_map)/size(cmap)) 1];

% Create foreground axes for the terrain:
ax(2) = axes;

% plot the terrain as a patch:
patch(ax(2),x,y,y)

% define the part of the colormap to use:
ax(2).CLim = [0 max(y)*(size(cmap)/size(tmap))];

% set the limits and axes visibility:
ylim([1 2*maxHight])
ax(1).Visible = 'off';
ax(2).Color = 'none';
linkprop(ax,'position');

% Display title.
title('Vertical Profile');

% Display legend underneath.
legend('Terrain', 'Location', 'southoutside');
```

Which will give you this figure:

[image: Terrain]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! I would really appreciate it if you could include an explanation of your workaround.

Comment: You welcome. I have added some explanations. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709620/matlab-colorbar-indicator-which-dynamical-change) for a more elaborate use of this method.

Comment: @Cebri, did you understand this solution? did it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for adding comments in the code. However I couldn't really test the entire solution because `patch(ax(2),x,y,y)` throws: `Error using patch. Vectors must be the same length.`

Comment: @Cebri, did you tried to just copy-paste-run the code above? It works fine for me, and you can see yourself that both `x` and `y` are 1-by-13 vectors: `x = [0, 0:10, 10]; y = [0, maxHight*rand(size(0:10)), 0];`

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted your code as is and I got the error. Just in case, I have copy-pasted it again but I keep getting the same error. I agree that the sizes of `x` and `y` are in accordance, but that may not be the problem. I am using R2015a. What version are you using?

Comment: I use 2016a, but I can't see any relevant difference. Just in case, I made some edit to the code above to make it more robust.