# Two colorbars for a matlab axes

Tags: matlab, colorbar, scatter

For the following matlab code:

```
figure;imshow( imread('cameraman.tif') ,[])
hold on;scatter(1:200,1:200,[],1:200);colorbar
```

As we can see, the color of scatter is gray because the colorbar of 'cameraman.tif' is gray. What if I want the colorbar of scatter is `jet` or `hsv`? I search some information from network, and I find that one axes has just one colorbar.

So, my question is that how to set the colorbar of `scatter` to `jet` and remain the colorbar of 'cameraman.tif' to be gray?

ZhQ

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39741044/2627163) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38233971/2627163)

Comment: (1) There is only one colormap per `figure` not `axes`. (2) In your code the scatter cannot be seen at all. (3) Do you want to show both axes with 2 different colorbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears in your [`scatter`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html). Take a look at [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html#inputarg_c) to see how you can define colors for `scatter`. I modified your code to:

```
figure;
imshow(imread('cameraman.tif'),[])
hold on
scatter(1:200,1:200,[],jet(200)) % this is what I changed
colorbar
```

and now it looks fine:

[image]

Comment: What if I want to assign the intensity of scatter points to 1:200? And I want the colorbar represent the color map of scatter points rather than the image. What can I do?

Comment: then you form your `jetmat = jet(200);` so you can use your scale like `jetmat((1:200),:)`. The scatter points do not have *colormap*. There is no straightforward way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I have find another solution for this problem:
[enter link description here](http://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52505-newcolorbar--multiple-colormaps-in-the-same-axes)